# How to get value of Child of childs from firebase in java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Data structure]

From this I want take the value of email from `mailID` and subject, title from mailText.i'm able to access the value of single child but when it show null with when try get with all three.

Following code working for single child:

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef = database.getReference("/");
    databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ArrayList<String> email = new ArrayList();
                     for (DataSnapshot sd: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                         String emailStr = sd.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                         email.add(emailStr);
                         System.out.println(email);
                         }
                     latch.countDown();
                     }
```

Above code gives me array contain the all email like that i want to take value of email,title and subject.

Comment: But there are multiple records beneath both nodes `mailId` and `mailText`. Which one would you like to get?

Comment: @AlexMamo i want all record from both child

Comment: Please give us a concrete example of the result that you expect.

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to take the value of email, subject, and title from all child

Comment: Before writing code, tell me please in which order you want the data to be displayed? Give am example of the output.

Comment: @AlexMamo email 
[abc@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com, abcd@gmail.com],

title
[test title],

subject
[test subject]

Comment: Is it ok for you to print for the first time all `email addresses` + `name` as separate rows and after that all `subject` + `titles` also in separate rows? The output should be: `abc@gmail.com / test`, next line `xyz@gmail.com, test` and after all this are displayed to display: `test body / text title`, and then on the next line `test body / text title` and so on?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes it will work for me

Comment: Ok, I'll write you some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `new` node is a direct child of your Firebase root, to achieve what you have explained in your comments, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference newRef = rootRef.child("new");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("mailID").getChildren()) {
            String email = ds.child("email").getValue(String.class);
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", email + " / " + name);
        }
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("mailText").getChildren()) {
            String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            String subject = ds.child("subject").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", title + " / " + subject);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
newRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

As you see, you need to attach a listener one step higher in your tree hierarchy and to loop throught the children using `getChildren()` method twice.

Comment: @worked and one question when i use String emailStr = sd.child("mailID").child("email").getKey(); it work fine show the key but when i try to print value it give the null value why?

Comment: You need to use: `ds.child("email").getKey()` inside the for loop. You're welcome, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the database structure(there is no join in firebase), to be able to query and get the required data:

```
new
  mailId
     email: userx@gmail.com
     name:userx
     title: test title
     Body: test body
```

Then you will be able to retrieve the required data for the user.

You can also use [Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) to be able to get the related data, example:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("new");
ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo("userx@gmail.com");
```