# Convert value with child into Java Object in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have read the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50696843/how-to-get-value-of-child-of-childs-from-firebase-in-java) on how get value with it's child in Firebase.

[image]

Now I want to convert that value into a Java object. Can I do that? If can, how I can achieve that?

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, please select them(this is just a reminder, if you wanted something else, you are welcomed to wait for other answers as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to convert that value into a Java object. Can I do that?

Of course you can! Actually I have answered that question too. So to solve this, first you need to create two POJO (model) classes:

```
class MailId {
    public String email, name;

    MailId() {}
}
```

And

```
class MailText {
    public String subject, title;

    MailText() {}
}
```

To get that data as objects of `MailId` and `MailText` classes, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference newRef = rootRef.child("new");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("mailID").getChildren()) {
            MailId mailId = ds.getValue(MailId.class);
            Log.d("TAG", mailId.email + " / " + mailId.name);
        }
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("mailText").getChildren()) {
            MailText mailText = ds.getValue(MailText.class);
            Log.d("TAG", mailText.subject + " / " + mailText.title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
newRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Um, this downvote is real, though. Shouldn't you implement the class to Serializable?

Comment: @GauravMall No, it should not. Firebase realtime database SDK deserializes objects that are coming from the database with the use of the public no-argument constructor and as you can see, it is present in my code. There is no need to implement `Serializable` since all properties are of type [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and all are serializable.

Comment: I was not unsure. I actually have built several apps, and always used Serializable. But now that I think about it they also contained integers and other data types. So yes you are right.